# Dynamic linq query c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a dynamic linq query on `IEnumerable<T>`. The following query I want to create dynamically:

```
.OrderByDescending(n => n.TS)
.GroupBy(n => n.PID)
.Select(n => n.First())
.Where(n => !n.IsD)
```

What I have tried is as under:

```
var type = typeof(TSource);
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(type, "n");
Expression tsExp = Expression.Property(pe, "TS");

MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
typeof(IEnumerable),
"OrderByDescending",
new Type[] { type.GetElementType() },
tsExp,
Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TSource>>>(pe, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

MethodCallExpression groupByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
typeof(IEnumerable),
"GroupBy",
new Type[] { type.GetElementType() },
orderByCallExpression,
Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TSource>>>(pe, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));


//Here how to create Select and Where expressions
//The issue with Select is it contains First() function call. How can i make it?

query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(groupByCallExpression);
```

I don't know how much my first try is correct, can anyone please help me out to create this query?

Comment: What about the query needs to be dynamic?  So far you're just building everything as constants, in which case you should just let the compiler do that for you by using lambdas.

Comment: The query needs to be dynamic because I have to apply it on object in reflection whose type is not known at compile time

Comment: As I said, we need to know *what* is going to be dynamic about the query.  You want to make as few things as possible be dynamic, everything that is known to be constant can be done without building everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going all the way long, you can try this:

```
var data = ((IEnumerable<object>)collection)
 .OrderByDescending(c => c.GetType().GetProperty("TS").GetValue(c))
 .GroupBy(c => c.GetType().GetProperty("PId").GetValue(c))
 .Select(c => c.First())
 .Where(c => !(bool)c.GetType().GetProperty("IsD").GetValue(c));
```

The validation is not present in the code - i assume that the object must have these properties otherwise you will get null reference exception.

Hope it helps!